# Is there an ideal operating system for GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome3

I love the UI of GNOME 3. I tried it in Fedora and Mint; is there an ideal Linux distribution/version for GNOME 3?

Comment: This question is too subjective.  Fedora works fine for many people and Mint doesn't use stock GNOME 3 by default.  Please read the [faq] and [ask] for information about how to ask a question suitable for this site.

Comment: FYI, "Linux version" refers to successive revisions of the Linux kernel.  Linux Mint and Fedora are bundles of programs using the Linux kernel and are called distributions.

Comment: Fedora 18 should work fine, and install easily. If not, report it as a bug. Note that Gnome 3 is quite demanding.

Comment: so the answer of my question is: no. right? ;) I didn't ask you about your favourite linux-version (that would be subjective). I just wanted to know, if there is an (objective) ideal version for GNOME. And your answers sounds like there isn't... :D

Comment: @Jere: Pay attention to the comments: you say "Linux-version", but what you mean is distribution. "Version" sounds as if you refer to the kernel (that is, source code). GNOME 3 is a mainstream project. So any mainstream distribution is fine. Also, (again, as said) it is demanding. If your computer is great, that doesn't matter. If your computer isn't, consider not using it (GNOME 3), **or** tune it (and other aspects of your overall system) to compensate. As a beginner, that's not done that easy; on the other hand, in the process, you'll learn a lot.

Comment: There isn't: I'd expect that GNOME 3 would work well in any distro that packages it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome aims to be distribution-independent. However, it happens to be that:

1. Fedora is the only major distribution shipping Gnome 3 as a default right now. Other distributions either have other defaults or no particular default. (And I'm sure there are some awesome smaller distributions defaulting to Gnome; I don't mean anything really deep with the word "major".)
2. Many Gnome developers are employed by Red Hat, which also sponsors Fedora and Fedora development. While the projects have different upstream goals, there's generally been a close relationship.

So, for those reasons, Fedora is likely as close to an "ideal" OS for Gnome 3 as exists. However, Gnome 3 should also work very well on any other modern Linux distro, and conversely, non-Gnome desktops work very well on Fedora.

Disclaimer: *I'm* a Fedora developer and work for Red Hat. Not directly on Gnome, though.

Comment: Is it correct to say, that Fedora is a test and invention zone for things that eventually end up in Red Hat?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg No. That's _one_ aspect of Fedora (and an important, useful one) but Fedora is a complete independent and functional distribution in its own right, with its own mission and community. But this is really whole 'nuther topic.